# 3.2.2 Installation Fail on MacOS

Tags: installation, osx

I am running a MacBook Pro 2019 with 32GB of memory and an AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8GB graphics card, Monterey 12.5.1, and I am getting an error message “You can’t open the application “Blender” because this application is not supported on this Mac.”

Any ideas?

Comment: If it’s helpful for anyone, I figured it out. You have to go to “Other Versions” and download the Mac Intel version if you don’t have a Silicon chipped Mac.

Comment: This might be useful to someone. I do recommend you add the solution as an answer to your own question.